# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hierynomus.smbj.SMBClient cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, smbj

I am developing an eclipse plugin. Within the plugin I have to access files in the shared drive, for that I'm using SMBJ java library. I have downloaded the jar and its dependencies from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/smbj) and included it in the build path. I have checked if the library is included in .classpath file, in bundle class path in MANIFEST.MF and in build.properties.

In order to test the plugin in Test Environment, I am exporting the plugin as 'Deployable Plugins and Fragments' (the exported jar also contains the libraries added) and including the jar in plugins folder of eclipse, but plugin complians that it cannot find the class during runtime.

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF and the build.properties

Comment: your previous comment of starting eclipse with -clean option actually helped. I don't see the problem anymore.